# xubuntu 12.04 doesn't seem to have option to not "sleep" computer

Tags: suspend, sleep

When I right-click on the battery and pursue the ac power setting options, there is no option to not put the computer to sleep. Is there a work around for this?  I want to transfer file all night.

Comment: How so? I can see the setting: "Put the computer to sleep when inactive for:", whose default values is "Never".

Answer (score 2):

I had adjusted the slider from never and forgotten that you have to slide it down (and not up) to get the "never" setting. So when you move the slider up, it maxes out at 5 hrs 50 something.

Comment: Anyway, problem solved....

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have installed xfce4-power-manager, If not install it with below command

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-power-manager
```

Then open it ,from there you can manage.

(I am not using lappy , else I can be more classified )

Comment: That package is installed by default in Xubuntu.

Comment: @enzotib I know that , I have already checked in my PC